# Multiple Offices / Locations with Microformats

Tags: microformats

I'm currently developing a website and I'd like to know how to **markup multiples offices** / locations with **Microformats**.

Currently, we have **two offices** (one in Sydney, NSW and Perth, WA) each with their individual phone number, name (i.e. Sydney Office) and location.

I've attempted to follow the article on marking up multiple addresses from Microformats.org, but seeing as I also have multiple phone numbers, I've run into a bit of a dilemma.

Here's what I currently have (just need to add in the respective phone number and office name)

```
<div class="vcard">
    <span class="fn org">
        <span class="value-title" title="Company Name"></span>
    </span>

    <div class="adr">
        <div class="street-address">20 Acme Road,</div>
        <span class="locality">Paddington</span>,
        <span class="region">NSW</span>
        <span class="postal-code">2021</span>
    </div>

    <div class="adr">
        <div class="street-address">220 Foo Road,</div>
        <span class="locality">Subiaco</span>,
        <span class="region">WA</span>
        <span class="postal-code">6008</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for org, you want to use the separate organization units, like so:

```
<div class="vcard">
    <span class="fn organization-name">
        <span class="value-title" title="Company Name">Company Name</span>
    </span>

    <div class="adr organization-unit">
        <div class="street-address">20 Acme Road,</div>
        <span class="locality">Paddington</span>,
        <span class="region">NSW</span>
        <span class="postal-code">2021</span>
    </div>

    <div class="adr organization-unit">
        <div class="street-address">220 Foo Road,</div>
        <span class="locality">Subiaco</span>,
        <span class="region">WA</span>
        <span class="postal-code">6008</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

you can validate/assure correct results here: http://hcard.geekhood.net/

as for multiple phone numbers, i'd apply the same theory. i know phone numbers have different `type` attributes.